# How To Insert Data with Spring Data JPA Relationships

Tags: json, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

hopefully this is an easy question, but I'm pretty new with JPA and having difficulty determining how to format a JSON POST request body that is sent to a Spring API. I have two entities, Product and Barcode with the following relationship:

- One Product can have many barcodes that point to it (OneToMany)
- One Barcode can point to only one Product (OneToOne)

The relationship is defined by a *product_id* column in the Barcode table.

Relationship definition in Barcode entity:

```
@OneToOne // one barcode relates to one product
private ProductEntity product;
```

The relationship definition in Product:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<BarcodeEntity> barcodes = new ArrayList<>();
```

My question is, how can I do a JSON POST request to insert a Barcode that is related to a Product already in the database? Would I need to pass the entire Product entity or is there a way to just pass the product_id alone?

How I would like to create a new Barcode entry when the Product already exists:

```
{ 
  "barcode": "string",
  "barcodeStatus": "string",
  "codeStandard": "string",
  "product": 1,
  "title": "string",
  "unitQuantity": 0
}
```

Instead of having to do the following, which I believe will result in an error because the product already exists:

```
{ 
  "barcode": "string",
  "barcodeStatus": "string",
  "codeStandard": "string",
  "product": {
     productInfo: "...",
     ....,
  },
  "title": "string",
  "unitQuantity": 0
}
```

Essentially, I'm trying to figure out how you can insert a new entity and define its relationship to another entity that is already present in the database. I'm sure I'm over complicating it.

Endpoint in Product controller:

```
@PostMapping(produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public ProductRest createProduct(@Valid @RequestBody ProductRequestModel productDetails) throws Exception {
    ProductRest returnValue = new ProductRest();

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    ProductDto productDto = modelMapper.map(productDetails, ProductDto.class);

    ProductDto createdProduct = productService.createProduct(productDto);
    returnValue = modelMapper.map(createdProduct, ProductRest.class);

    return returnValue;
}
```

createProduct method in Product service file:

```
public ProductDto createProduct(ProductDto product) {
    if (productRepo.findByTitle(product.getTitle()) != null)
        throw new ServiceException("Record with matching title already exists");

    // Set product id for each barcode
    for (int i = 0; i < product.getBarcodes().size(); i++) {
        ProductBarcodeDto barcode = product.getBarcodes().get(i);
        barcode.setProduct(product); 
        product.getBarcodes().set(i, barcode);
    }

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    ProductEntity productEntity = modelMapper.map(product, ProductEntity.class);

    ProductEntity storedProductDetails = productRepo.save(productEntity); 

    ProductDto returnValue = modelMapper.map(storedProductDetails, ProductDto.class);
    return returnValue;
}
```

Fields in ProductDto (defines getters/setters and empty constructor; just not shown):

```
public class ProductDto {

private long id;
private List<BarcodeDto> barcodes;
private String title;
private String description;
private String SKU;
private ProductVariationDto variation;
private double cost;
private double retailPrice;
private LocalDate launchDate;
private LocalDate discontinueDate;
private String discontinueReason;
private String salesChannel;
private LabelDto label;
private int secondaryStockLevel;
private int primaryStockLevel;
private LocalDateTime modifiedDate;
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
private String productStatus;
private List<SupplierDto> suppliers;
}
```

I had it set up so that ProductRequestModel expected a BarcodeEntity. Is this the correct or should I change it to expect just an integer value for the Barcode ID?

createBarcode endpoint in Barcode Controller:

```
@PostMapping(produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public BarcodeRest createBarcode(@Valid @RequestBody BarcodeRequestModel barcodeDetails) throws Exception {
    BarcodeRest returnValue = new BarcodeRest();

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    BarcodeDto barcodeDto = modelMapper.map(barcodeDetails, BarcodeDto.class);

    BarcodeDto createdBarcode = barcodeService.createBarcode(barcodeDto);
    returnValue = modelMapper.map(createdBarcode, BarcodeRest.class);

    return returnValue;
}
```

createBarcode method implementation:

```
public BarcodeDto createBarcode(BarcodeDto barcode) {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    if (barcodeRepo.findByBarcode(barcode.getBarcode()) != null)
        throw new ServiceException("Barcode value already exists.");

    BarcodeEntity barcodeEntity = modelMapper.map(barcode, BarcodeEntity.class);
    BarcodeEntity storedBarcode = barcodeRepo.save(barcodeEntity);

    BarcodeDto returnValue = modelMapper.map(storedBarcode, BarcodeDto.class);
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there seems to be an issue with the Database Schema Mapping:

One Product : Many Barcodes (One to Many) [NO ISSUES]

Many Barcodes : One Product (Many to One, instead of One to One) [HAS ISSUES]

Secondly, yes you can use just the 'product_id' to update the barcode. It'd be better if you post the controller code once. Would be easier to find any issues with that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the controller endpoint code for creating a Product and Barcode to the original post. Why is Many Barcodes : One Product an issue? The reasoning behind the ManyToOne is that a product may have a barcode that points to 1 unit of that product and another barcode that points to a case of say 50 units of that product. Is there a better approach for handling that?